# space underneath footer, wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, footer

I am making my first wordpress homepage, and something on the frontpage really annoys me. Underneath my copyright footer there is some empty space which i cannot get rid of, my footer is only 13px in height so it must be something else. If you want to take a look

test.virumfarveogtapet.dk

Comment: Try to narrow the problem down. Hint, check your SVG.

Comment: `.elementor-34 .elementor-element.elementor-element-2e5b248b` strange class btw. needs to have overflow hidden, since there is one element to big in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with your svg height.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a ton, that Solved it :)

Answer (score 0):

You have a svg with a 470px height.
Add this to your css file:

```
.elementor-34 .elementor-element.elementor-element-2e5b248b > .elementor-shape-top svg {
    width: calc(200% + 1.3px);
    height: 0px;
}
```